# Proving an inequality with given equality of the form $a^2+b^2=c$

Tags: inequality

$$\begin{Bmatrix}
a^2+b^2=2\\ 
c^2+d^2=4
\end{Bmatrix} \to ac+bd\le3 $$ prove that inequality

Comment: Is it supposed to be $ac+bd\leq3$?

Comment: yes...I corrected it

Answer (score 2):

This is false, take $a=b=1$ and $c=2$, $d=0$. Then $ac+bc=4$.

Comment: I think it's supposed to be $ac+bd$, but as it stands, you're right.

Comment: @user259462 Was the textbook wrong or did you mistype it ?

Comment: I mistyped it sorry

Comment: @user259462 No problem. I find the solution using the Brahmagupta Identity very nice...

Answer (score 2):

WLOG $a=\sqrt2\cos A, b=\sqrt2\sin A,c=2\cos B,d=2\sin B$

$ac+bd=2\sqrt2\cos(A-B)\le2\sqrt2$

$ac+bc=c(a+b)=2\cos B\cdot\sqrt2(\cos A+\sin A)$

Now $\cos A+\sin A=\sqrt2\cos\left(A-\dfrac\pi4\right)\le\sqrt2$

Can you take it home from here?

Comment: This exercise is taken from a relatively early class textbook and trigonometry has not been taught

Comment: @user259462, Find my other answer!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Using [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity),

$$(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=2\cdot4$$

$$(ad-bc)^2\ge0\implies (ac+bd)^2\le8$$

The equality occurs if $ad-bc=0$

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Note that $$(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2\ge0$$so that $$a^2+c^2+b^2+d^2\ge2ac+2bd$$

---

This deals with the easy inequality required. Other answers give a sharper result, which is possible because it is impossible for $a=c$ and $b=d$ with the given conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by Cauchy Schwarz inequality:
$$8=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\ge(ac+bd)^2$$
gives a tighter bound.